# Is it possible to use libsvm for multilabel regression problems

Tags: machine-learning, svm, libsvm

I have a scenario where I need to predict spherical co-ordinates (r,theta,phi) depending upon the values of 6 attributes.I am using Libsvm with regression option. If I individually predict labels according to the object instance, it doesnt make sense. Also if I combine labels and assign a specific label for each r,theta,phi, it is not meaningful and SVM not converging in prediction. I want SVM to analyse the combination of three coordinates and accordingly create a training model. Is it possible? Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Not really: SVM is a classification algorithm, not a prediction algorithm.  So far as SVM is concerned, a label of (0, 0, 1) is just as distinct from (0, 0, 2) as it is from (20, 3, -1): "not the same".

If you have a regression problem, then use a regression model: do a little research to find one that matches whatever your data set characteristics suggest.

---

**UPDATE PER OP COMMENT**

From what little you've said, it sounds to me as if you want a multivariate regression, with a single loss function that describes the deviation from the desired output triple.  You're correct that three separate regressions won't work for this scenario: the position in space depends on a non-linear combination of the three outputs.

I suggest that you make your loss function some useful distance function between the true and predicted positions.  You will need to experiment with your model features, using linear, squared, and other terms for each of the six inputs.  I can't suggest anything, as you haven't adequately described the problem.

Comment: I did research in regression models, but with not much luck for multi output scenarios. it is suggested to either combine multiple labels and define a new label, or do regrssion based on each one of the multiple labels. it doesnt work for me. I want to treat the multiple output as a combination and predict based on that.